Issue with updating user profiles via PUT request in Slim Framework
I'm working on a school project where I'm using PHP, Slim Framework, and MySQL to develop an API. I'm encountering an issue when attempting to update user profiles via a PUT request to the /updateuser/{cc_105_id} endpoint.
When I send a PUT request with the required fields (cc_105_profile, cc_105_fullname, cc_105_email) filled in Postman, I'm consistently getting the following error message:
{
"error": true,
"message": "Required parameters cc_105_profile, cc_105_fullname, cc_105_email are missing or      empty"
}
This is the relevant code for it :
`$app->put('/updateuser/{cc_105_id}', function(Request $request, Response $response, array     $args){
    $cc_105_id = $args['cc_105_id'];

    // Check if required parameters are present and not empty
    if(!haveEmptyParam($request, $response, array('cc_105_profile', 'cc_105_fullname',         'cc_105_email'))) {

        $request_data = $request->getParsedBody();
        error_log(print_r($request_data, true));

        // Log the values of cc_105_profile, cc_105_fullname, and cc_105_email
        error_log("cc_105_profile: " . $request_data['cc_105_profile']);
        error_log("cc_105_fullname: " . $request_data['cc_105_fullname']);
        error_log("cc_105_email: " . $request_data['cc_105_email']);

        $cc_105_profile = $request_data['cc_105_profile'];
        $cc_105_email = $request_data['cc_105_email'];
        $cc_105_fullname = $request_data['cc_105_fullname'];

        // Fetch the user's username from the database or request data
        // Assuming it's present in the request data, adjust this according to your setup
        $cc_105_username = $request_data['cc_105_username']; 

        // Process the update operation here
        $db = new DbOperations;

        // Check the result of the update operation
        if ($db->updateuser($cc_105_profile, $cc_105_fullname, $cc_105_email, $cc_105_id)) {
        // If the update was successful
        $response_data = array(); 
        $response_data['error'] = false; 
        $response_data['message'] = 'User Updated Successfully';
        $user = $db->getUserByUsername($cc_105_email); // Fetch user by username
        $response_data['user'] = $user; 

        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($response_data));
        return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')->withStatus(200);
    } else {
        // If the update failed
        $response_data = array(); 
        $response_data['error'] = true; 
        $response_data['message'] = 'Please try again later';
        $user = $db->getUserByUsername($cc_105_email); // Fetch user by email
        $response_data['user'] = $user; 
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($response_data));
        return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')->withStatus(200);
        }
    }  
    return $response
    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    ->withStatus(200);
});

function haveEmptyParam($request, $response, $required_params) {
    $error = false; 
    $error_params = '';
    $request_params = $request->getParsedBody(); 

    foreach($required_params as $param) {
        if(!isset($request_params[$param]) || strlen($request_params[$param]) <= 0) {
            $error = true; 
            $error_params .= $param . ', ';
        }
    }

    if($error) {
        $error_detail = array();
        $error_detail['error'] = true; 
        $error_detail['message'] = 'Required parameters ' . substr($error_params, 0, -2) . '     are missing or empty';
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($error_detail));
        return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')->withStatus(400);
    }
return $error; 
}

`
What I've Tried:
I ensured that the required fields (cc_105_profile, cc_105_fullname, cc_105_email) are present in the request body.
I've checked the haveEmptyParam function to ensure it's correctly checking for empty parameters.
Expected Outcome:
I expect the code to successfully update the user profile and return a response with a success message and the updated user details.
Actual Outcome:
Despite providing values for the required parameters, the code always executes the     haveEmptyParam code block, indicating that the required parameters are missing or empty.
Additional Information:
I've included an image of my Postman request setup for reference.
How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the user profiles are successfully updated?

Make sure to add the BodyParsing middleware:
$app->addBodyParsingMiddleware();

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/middleware/body-parsing.html

Thank you odan !
with a little debugging when adding that to my code, it seems to be working now.

Very good. Can you please accept this answer?
